# Counting the lines of a compressed file

Tags: python, file-system, compression

This is a Python script for counting the lines of a compressed file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gzip, bz2, zipfile, os, sys

def openZip(zfile):
    f = zipfile.ZipFile(zfile)
    firstFile = f.filelist[0].filename
    if firstFile.endswith("/"):
        raise Exception("This zip file contains a directory.")
    return f.open(firstFile)

class compressedFile:
    fileOpenerDict = {".gz":gzip.open, ".bz2":bz2.open, ".zip":openZip}

    def __init__(self, pFilePath):
        self.filePath = os.path.abspath(pFilePath)
        self.fileStem, self.ext = os.path.splitext(self.filePath)
        self.ext = self.ext.lower()
        try:
            self.fileOpener = self.fileOpenerDict[self.ext]
        except KeyError:
            print("Only gz, zip, and bz2 files allowed.")
            exit(1)

    def countLines(self):
        nLines = 0
        with self.fileOpener(self.filePath) as fh:
            for line in fh:
                nLines = nLines + 1
        return nLines

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = compressedFile(sys.argv[1])
    n = c.countLines()
    print("N lines: %d" % n)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Coding style

You should follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official coding style guide of Python.
The most notable violations:

- Don't put all those imports on a single line, use multiple lines
- Use `CamelCase` for class names
- Use `snake_case` for function and variable names

#### Simplify and improve `__init__`

Don't create class member attributes that you don't need.
For example `self.fileStem` is completely unused,
and `self.ext` could be replaced with a local variable.
Don't pollute your class with unnecessary elements.

Exception handling is best for dealing with anomalies.
If the script is used with a file with an unsupported extension,
that's not really an anomaly.
It would be better to handle this with an `if` statement instead.

It's not a good idea to exit from the constructor of a class:
the main method of the program should be in charge of shutting down or not.
It would be better to define a custom exception,
make the constructor raise it, and let the main method handle it.

The custom exception can be as simple as this:

```
class UnsupportedCompressionException(Exception):
    pass
```

The constructor with the above suggestions applied:

```
def __init__(self, filepath):
    ext = os.path.splitext(filepath)[1].lower()
    if ext not in self.fileOpenerDict:
        raise UnsupportedCompressionException("Only gz, zip, and bz2 files allowed.")
    self.filepath = filepath
    self.fileOpener = self.fileOpenerDict[ext]
```

The main method handling the exception:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        c = CompressedFile(sys.argv[1])
        n = c.count_lines()
        print("N lines: %d" % n)
    except UnsupportedCompressionException as e:
        print(e)
        exit(1)
```

#### Improve `count_lines`

It would be better to do the counting and return the result from inside the `with`.
This is because in general it's best to limit all code to the smallest possible scope.

The `line` loop variable is unused.
It's customary to use `_` as the loop variable name in such case.

Instead of `count = count + 1`, it's more common and recommended to write `count += 1`.

As a result, the method becomes:

```
def count_lines(self):
    with self.fileOpener(self.filepath) as fh:
        count = 0
        for _ in fh:
            count += 1
        return count
```